# Python How to Compare Two File Lines

Tags: python

I need a automated way of getting C programming exam cheaters. The first thing I want to do is compare two files and thought I could do it comparing the line of a file with all the lines of another, if equals then a counter receives +1.

One smart thing to do is to ignore all spaces and `{}` but I don't know a smart way of doing it, I see that the `.replace()` made the performance really bad, any other solution? Basically what I did so far but not working as I want:

```
def line_compare(filename1, filename2):
    counter = 0
    result = {}
    with open(filename1) as codefile1:
        with open(filename2) as codefile2:
            lines1 = codefile1.readlines()
            lines2 = codefile2.readlines()
            for line1 in lines1:
                for line2 in lines2:
                    if line1 == line2:
                        counter += 1
            key = filename1 + " " + filename2
            result[key] = counter / len(lines1)
    return result
```

The idea of the dict is putting the name of the two files as key and the value is the percentage of the code that would be probably copied. It is giving me a lot of false-positive, is this the best way of doing it in python?

Comment: Sorry, I thought about clonedigger but it won't work for C code

Comment: @Gribouillis Does clonedigger process C code? He is writing a plagiarism checker in Python, but comparing C.

Answer (score 0):

About the white space and {}, a first step could involve reformatting the source files with a code beautifier such as [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/). This would give both programs the exact same formatting. Astyle can also perform small tasks such as remove comments.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find copied-and-pasted code by inspecting individual lines isn't the way to go, for two reasons: (1) many false positives, as you noted -- every blank line, every `if x:` line and so on will show as matches, and those aren't evidence of a problem. Then (2) a really easy way to plagiarize code would be to add a small but irrelevant change to every line, like change every variable name by adding `xxx` to the end, or even just adding an extra comment or space on every line!

You want to move away from code lines and instead focus on the overall structure of the code -- looking for similarities in the abstract syntax tree would probably be a more productive approach.

Comment: A python module such as [pycparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycparser) should be able to produce an abstract syntax tree for the script.

Comment: The `ast` module would be simpler.

Comment: Do you think `ast` can handle C code syntax trees ?

Comment: I stand corrected -- the tool is in Python but the code being examined is C, you are correct.